Generate ERD for each table in postgres database
I need to create individual ERD(Entity Relationship Diagram) for a list of tables. For example, if there are 100 tables, I would need 100 separate ERDs. Each ERD will include the main table (for which the ERD is generated) along with any related tables connected through relationships.
While DBeaver can generate these diagrams, doing it manually becomes cumbersome when there are many tables.
I’d like to automate this process with a script that accepts the table schema, table name, and output directory as inputs, and then generates the ERD in the specified directory. This approach would be especially useful when switching between databases or performing this task on a regular basis, such as monthly or quarterly.

What do you mean by ERD in the first place? There's no such file format and each tool has its own way of creating and storing diagrams. And what would such a single-table diagram contain?

One possibility would be to write information schema queries that generate PlantUML strings. The query could return the column text, eg Born : DATE  in each row, with the first and last lines including the entity definition and closing bracket

@PanagiotisKanavos An entity relationship diagram (ERD) is a visual representation of a database's structure and the relationships between its tables. In dbever we can export ERD as .PNG.

I know what an ERD is, I don't know what you mean by it and what output you expect. When there's only a single table in the diagram, what relationships do you expect to show? A PNG is an image format, not a diagram. It's not the best for diagrams either, SVG is better. A diagram can be rendered as a picture. You can easily generate PlantUML text diagrams from tables and then render them to SVG or PNG. If you google for plantuml postgresql you'll find tools in various languages that read the schema information and generate PlantUML files

And you still haven't explained which ERD you want. People have used Entity Relationship Diagram to refer to different things. People talk about ERD when they actually want database diagrams. DBeaver's diagrams are largely UML class diagrams with special formatting. You can easily generate one PlantUML file per table using just SQL queries, but it's easier to write a tool in whatever client language you're comfortable with. You can extract the formatting into a separate file and include it in the generated files

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your attention here. I will look into the PlantUML.
Each ERD will include the main table (for which the ERD is generated) along with any related tables connected through relationships. I don't mean full database diagrams here.I understand that PNG is image format & i dont mind ERD rendered as PNG. Also, having special formatting is good but not mandotory.

For example, if there are 100 tables, I would need 100 separate ERDs. This is a conflicting question; the number of tables has no relation with the "number" of ERDs. One database has just one ERD. The ERD could be from one table if there is just one table, but also 100 tables when you have 100.
